# NestJS useless *.d.ts files

Tags: nestjs

NESTJS frameworks tsconfig.json  by default has a rule:

`...
"declaration": true,
...`

I see no usege for *.d.ts file created in /dist folder 
Can I remove *.d.ts files from /dist or set

```
   "declaration": false,
```

Will it cause some errors? Or `"declaration": true` set on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"declaration": true` is useful for when you are creating npm packages to be used in  typescript, which is one thing that you can do with NestJS. If you are just building a webserver however, the declaration isn't necessarily needed. Up to you if you want to keep it.

Comment: Can you show some doc or example please "how to create npm package with NestJS" ?

Comment: https://dev.to/nestjs/publishing-nestjs-packages-with-npm-21fm probably one of the better guides to it, in my honest opinion

Comment: Cool ! Thanks for contentful answer )